# string format using with increment

Tags: vb.net

i have a ticket_no field which has a format of "storecode - datetoday - n"  what i'm trying to is when as long as the date is today the "n" will just increment but if the date changes the "n" will reset to 1.

```
    TMP_SQL = "select max(ticket_no) from tbl_main where store_id = '" + frm_store.store_code + "'"
    Dim OBJCMD As New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL, OBJCON)
    OBJREADER = OBJCMD.ExecuteReader()
    Dim ydate As String
    ydate = Now.ToString("MMddyy")
    With OBJREADER
        .Read()
        Dim x As string
        Dim str As String

        If IsDBNull(OBJREADER(0)) = False Then
            str = OBJREADER(0)
            x = Int32.Parse(OBJREADER(0).ToString().Split("-")(1))
            If x <> ydate Then
                tmp = 0
                tmp = Int32.Parse(OBJREADER(0).ToString().Split("-")(2)) + 1
            Else
                tmp = Int32.Parse(OBJREADER(0).ToString().Split("-")(2)) + 1
            End If
        End If

    End With

    txtTicketno.Text = frm_store.store_code & "-" & Now.ToString("MMddyy") & "-" & tmp
```

Comment: What is the content of OBJREADER(0) before your attempts to split it?

Comment: hi i got it all figured out i used sql substring to split the middle part of the string and i put a condition using that middle part with the date today thx